# Heroku install error, using omniauth for first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, omniauth

I just tried to upload a new version of my app. I'm trying to implement omniauth for the first time. Its working locally just fine. Omniauth may not be the issue. Please help. The error I am getting when I do "git push heroku" is:

```
$ git push heroku
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Murpl/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 166, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (119/119), done.
Writing objects: 100% (124/124), 33.20 KiB, done.
Total 124 (delta 80), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
Using --without development:test
Windows Gemfile.lock detected, ignoring it.
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
**/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/requirement.rb:134:in `satisfied_by?': undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)**
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `all?'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/requirement.rb:134:in `each'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/requirement.rb:134:in `all?'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/requirement.rb:134:in `satisfied_by?'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:125:in `matches_spec?'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/index.rb:47:in `search_for_all_platforms'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/index.rb:47:in `select'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/index.rb:47:in `search_for_all_platforms'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:364:in `search'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:354:in `gems_size'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:179:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `sort_by'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:175:in `each'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:175:in `sort_by'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:175:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:344:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `catch'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:343:in `resolve_requirement'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:295:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `reverse_each'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:294:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:160:in `start'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `catch'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:151:in `resolve'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:85:in `resolve_remotely!'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:35:in `run'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/bundle:19
FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
! Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 1
To git@heroku.com:hollow-journey-210.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:hollow-journey-210.git'
```

Comment: Any chance [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974257/push-rails-app-to-heroku) is the same issue?

Comment: No. If it helps this is my Gemfile contents:
`gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :group => :development
gem 'authlogic', '>= 3.0.0'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 0.2.6'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2"
gem 'omniauth', '~> 0.2.0'`

Comment: If I comment out omniauth, it works fine. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: add your gemfile to the question instead, makes it easier to read with new lines.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that has this issue I had to revert to omniauth 0.2.5 to get it to work.