# Unable to publish to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, installation, heroku

I am using OS X.

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]

rails -v
Rails 3.0.8

which ruby
/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby

which rails
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bin/rails
```

When i use the command `git push heroku master`, I get

```
!     Heroku push rejected, no Rails or Rack app detected

To git@heroku.com:testingnewyork.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:testingnewyork.git'
```

What should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [push rails app to heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974257/push-rails-app-to-heroku)

Answer (score 2):

Looks similar to this question: [push rails app to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974257/push-rails-app-to-heroku)

If you didn't run the git commands inside a Rails app, Heroku has no idea what you're pushing :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change directory into the application folder:

```
rails new testingnewyork
cd testingnewyork
```